# 配列の要素を持つモデルに対して関連付けを書く方法を教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

InquiryType（お問い合わせ種類）とInquiryContent（お問い合わせ内容）というモデルがあり、それぞれ以下の要素を持っています。Railsのマイグレーションファイルを書きます。

InquiryType:

```
class CreateInquiryTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inquiry_types do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamp :created_at
    end
  end
end
```

InquiryContent:

```
class CreateInquiryContents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inquiry_contents do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :mail_address, null: false
      t.integer :inquiry_type_id, array: true
      t.string :content, null: false
      t.timestamp :created_at
    end
  end
end
```

InquiryContentはinquiry_type_id（InquiryTypeのid）要素を持ちますが、配列でもっています。

具体的に以下のようなことをやりたいです。

例えば、InquiryContentの最初のレコードの`inquiry_type_id`の値が`[1, 3, 4, 5]`を持っているとします。
その上で、`InquiryContent.first.inquiry_type`のようなコードの書き方で該当するInquiryTypeのレコードを全て抽出できるようにしたいと思っています。

その場合、どのような関連を書けばよいでしょうか？
もしくはモデル設計を変えた方が良いでしょうか？

ちなみにInquiryContentに`belongs_to :inquiry_type`、 InquiryTypeに`has_many :inquiry_contents`の関連を書きましたがダメでした。。
このように関連を書くと`InquiryContent.first.inquiry_type`で`nil`が返ってきてしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Railsのアソシエーション機能を**利用せず**に `InquiryContent#inquiry_types` で該当するInquiryTypeのリストを得たいだけであれば、次のように定義することで可能です。

```
class InquiryContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def inquiry_types
    InquiryType.where :id => inquiry_type_id
  end
end
```

Railsの流儀で (アソシエーションを使って) 処理したい場合には、PostgreSQL独自の "配列" を利用せずに `has_many :through` を使用した N:N の関係を定義する必要があります。

参考: [Active Record の関連付け (アソシエーション)](http://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。配列を利用した関連は書けなさそうなので、データベース設計から見直したほうが良さそうですね。